# Running Sybase SQL commands from DOS/Windows batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch-file, sybase

Is there any way I can run Sybase SQL commands from command prompt. I need to write a batch file which runs an SQL query on machine as a fix for a bug.

Comment: i think this link may help
http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/aut96/sy-intro.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use ISQL.  See http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.help.ase_15.0.utility/html/utility/utility10.htm for the complete reference.

Specifically, you're looking for commands like this:

```
ISQL -S server -D database -U user -P password
```

This will launch ISQL with the indicated settings, and from there you can run SQL statements against the database.

Comment: i have isql.jar coming with  SQL Anywhere 9. Is that the one? where can I get isql.exe?

Comment: I believe that it's a part of the Adaptive Server installation.

Comment: I couldn't seem to find this executable in Sybase 11. Any idea if it still exists? I only see the .jar file as well.

Comment: Without any information on where to find this utility, the answer is useless.

Comment: @MickJ: See page http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc35456.1570/html/ocspsunx/X33477.htm.  This should definitely be included in a normal sybase installation.